# How to use Google's ARCore in MAUI Blazor application

Tags: arcore, maui-blazor

I am building a mobile app using Maui Blazor and .NET 7.
I need google augmented reality services (aka Google ARCore) in it.
How to use those services in MAUI Blazor?
I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check this [Getting started with ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/getting-started) for more information.

Second, you can use the [Xamarin.Google.ARCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.ARCore/1.29.0) nuget package in your project.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I can use Xamarin libraries in Maui. I will try

Comment: @Luka Hi did you manage to get your app in Maui working with google AR? Do you have any example of how an implementation would look like? Thx

Comment: @Nysand, at the end I did managed to run it, but not without problem. I had to use Xamaring Bindings to import Googles ArCore Jar files into my project( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar) also import JavaGL,. And my experience is that this is unusable. So I abandoned this project.

Comment: Thanks @Luka, I was also trying to get something working in Maui but had to abandon.

Comment: I have published updated .NET bindings for ARCore on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPACE.Google.ARCore I tested them using the HelloAR sample app on MAUI and they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, I have published updated .NET bindings for ARCore on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPACE.Google.ARCore
I tested them using the HelloAR sample app on MAUI and they seem to work fine!